# Jquery click action doesn't work to ajax appended dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Like in the screenshot I have div element working as button to expand area inside `comments-loaded-more-wrap` div element. Inside this div there are paragraphs if that div contains any text content. If there are no paragraphs `comments-load-more` div don't appear at first. It appears after I add text from input element. So I'm appending texts inside `comments-loaded-more-wrap`. but after append my expand jquery doesn't work. When I refresh the page its working fine.

I want to know how to reload the element to inherit jquery or is there any way to solve it?

[image]

If there is not content highlighted button don't appear at first. It comes when I add something from comment field. But when I click button the jquery doesn't work. If there are more that button is there at first time and it's working if I add something from comment field.

Here is the graphical view of my button:

[image]

here is my data append ajax:

```
//get comment input box id by its name
    var elements = document.getElementsByName( 'comment_input' );

    //on enter key press
    $(elements).each(function(){
        var cmt_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var resp = cmt_id.split("_");

        $('#comment_post_'+resp[2]).on('click', function(event) {

            var comment = $('#'+cmt_id).text();
            var form_data = {
                comment_input : comment,
                post_Id : resp[2],
                ajax : '1'  
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "comment/post_comment/",
                type: 'POST',
                async : true,
                dataType:"json",
                data: form_data,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#'+cmt_id).text('');
                    var latest_comment = data;
                    print_latest_comment(latest_comment);
                }
            });
        });
    });


function print_latest_comment(data){    
        $ght = $('#post_comment_id_'+ data.post_Id + ' .mCSB_container').children().length;
        if($ght==0){
            $('#post_comment_id_'+ data.post_Id + ' #panel1').append('<div class="comments-load-more" id="more-load-'+ data.post_Id +'">'+
                        '<span class="load-more-comments-count"><span class="new_cmt_count_'+ data.post_Id +'"></span></span>'+
                    '</div>');
            $( '#post_comment_id_'+ data.post_Id + ' .mCSB_container'  ).append('<div class="post-meta-single-comment" name="comment-field" id="comment_'+ data.comment_id +'">'+
                    '<div class="post-exp-top-meta-left">'+
                        '<div class="post-exp-top-meta-left-profile-picture">'+
                            '<a href="user?id='+ data.user_Id +'" ><img src="uploads/'+ data.pro_image.name + data.pro_image.ext +'"/></a>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="post-exp-top-meta-left-profile-info">'+
                            '<div class="post-exp-top-meta-left-profile-name">'+
                                '<a href="user?id='+ data.user_Id +'" >'+ data.user_details.full_name +'</a>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="post-exp-top-meta-left-profile-modes">'+
                                '<ul>'+
                                    '<li><div class="time"><abbr class="timeago" title="'+ data.comment_datetime +'">less than a minute ago</abbr></div></li>'+
                                    '<li class="flag"></li>'+
                                '</ul>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="post-meta-single-comment-vote">'+
                        '<a class="comment-edit_'+ data.comment_id +'" title="Edit Comment" id="comment-edit">Edit</a>'+
                        '<i class="fa fa-times fa-2 close-comment" style="display: none;" title="Remove Comment" id="delete_comment_'+ data.comment_id +'"></i>'+
                        '<div class="comment-count">6</div>'+
                        '<div class="comment-icon"></div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="clearfix"></div>'+
                    '<div class="comment-content comment_content_'+ data.comment_id +'">'+
                        '<span class="comment-content-alone_'+ data.comment_id +'">'+ data.content +'</span>'+
                        '<input type="text" id="edit_comment_'+ data.comment_id +'" name="cmt_edit_input" style="display:none; padding:5px; height: 30px;" value="'+ data.content +'" spellcheck="true" />'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'
            );
        }
}  // function end
```

Comment: There's no AJAX here, no click({function(). Is this everything?

Comment: What is being returned in the success data?

Comment: on which element click event is not working ?

Comment: @DanWhite I have updated ajax code and added graphical view of my button.

Comment: @Nishan where is your button click event which is not working ?have you added in question ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to know how to reload the element to inherit jquery or is there any way to solve it?

If you add a button after pageload

```
$('#myNewButton').on('click', function....
```

Then it wont work, as the javascript has run, and it's not going to rerun to bind the click event to your post-ready button.

Instead, do this.

```
$('#myContainerThatExistsInSourceCode').on('click', '#myNewButton', function()....
```

This binds the clickevent to the parent, of your button, so the children wont have an event bound to it, but the child will trigger the event bound to the parent.

Comment: So do I need to add a new class to appended element? I am using same classes to the appended element as in the elements on page load.

Comment: I was only answering how you add events like 'click' to an element you add after pageload. The point is that after the javascript file has been executed and all the event-binding has been done, further dynamically added elements wont have those events bound to them. So if you bind a click event to the container of the dynamically added elements like i showed in the answer, you get around this problem

Answer (score -1):

```
   $('body').on('click', '#comment_post_'+resp[2], function(event) {
        var comment = $('#'+cmt_id).text();
        var form_data = {
            comment_input : comment,
            post_Id : resp[2],
            ajax : '1'  
   };
```

Comment: You should explain why the OP must use Event Delegation here, or better yet flag it as a duplicate of any number of previous questions about this : )

Comment: I would explain if I knew how it worked.  I just know it works.